# How to synch Facebook deauthorization callback with Facebook Javascript SDK

Tags: python, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm using the Facebook Python and Javascript SDKs.  And have a deauthorization callback url set up to accept POSTs from Facebook in the event a User deauthorizes the applicaiton.

When I receive the POST from Facebook, I set the User to inactive, and will not log them into the site.  However this leaves fb:login-button out of synch.  It doesn't show the User data (because I am passing a null User to the template), but a **logout button** is being displayed.  I assume because it is getting the user state from the fb Cookie.

There's obviously some additional clean up I need to do, and so my question is how do I clean up state in the login-button?

Comment: Wanted to follow up on this issue.  It turns out that the Facebook Javascript SDK *does* handle deauthorization as expected, but in my code there was a conflict with Facebook's new 'send' button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i understood the problem correctly: 
Try to check the user authorization using something like that: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.getLoginStatus/
And then do with your buttons whatever you want...

Comment: While trying to construct that call I noticed that the javascript API is already doing that.  So the problem ended up being a conflict with some other Facebook javascript.